# 18.04 re-install

Tags: 18.04, reinstall

I've currently 18.04.2 LTS installed on my desktop. For some reasons, I want to re-install it (the same version). Some malfunctions have motivated this idea. (occasional freezes, online & local audio streams running on a loop from time to time as in a used CD, black Ubuntu screen blinking while start-up and not advancing towards the Session Opening screen...

Is it safe to do so through the 'Startup Disk Creator' - will it work to install the same version?

I'll be doing it by a USB. While installing it the previous time, I think I had removed the USB at a wrong point. When exactly should I remove the USB? After the installation process, I should generally get the prompt to remove it. Instead, I was invited to re-boot the computer without getting the prompt to remove the key. Will I get the prompt after re-boot?

18.04.2 LTS; 3.28.2; 64-bit; Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz x 2; AMD Rv730

Comment: As I can remember the prompt to remove the USB is after / during shutdown after installation process. There you will be ask if you want to restart or try the Live Session further.

Comment: If you get to the screen asking you to reboot or continuing using the live system, the installation is finished, it does not matter if you remove the USB at this point. You should although, remove your USB once the live system has shutdown, for the sake of your USB.

Answer (score 1):

> When exactly should I remove the USB?

You get asked to remove it as a text in the console. So after the graphics are gone.

> Will I get the prompt after re-boot?

While it is doing the shutdown part of a reboot.

By the way: there is a pretty large time frame at the end where you can basically press shutdown. remove the installer and it will still boot normally. Happens once every so often that my install stalls after installing. If your system crashed when the popup "installation done. do you want to reboot or continue  using the live session" the system has finished installing. Happened to me last time and hard shutdown with booting got me into my installed Ubuntu.